# CSS Mask Transition for Vuejs

Tags: css, vuejs2, css-transitions

I have been trying to recreate this mask css effect as router-view transition.

https://tympanus.net/codrops/2016/09/29/transition-effect-with-css-masks/

And I tried to map the sample code to Vuejs transition states.  But I am not getting any animation effect as if the mask-play never happened or it happens too quickly that I didn't see anything.  I am not sure if this is doable but I did create a Vue page where the effect works, just not during route transition.

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

App.vue  (Below code not working as router-view transition)

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
   
      <transition :name="transitionName" mode="in-out" >
        <router-view class="view child-view"
                     keep-alive></router-view>
      </transition>
   
  </div>
</template>


<script>
  
  export default {
    name: 'app',
    methods: {     
    },
    watch: {
      '$route'(to, from) { 
          this.transitionName = 'mask-nature1';
      },
    },
    data() {
      return {
        
      };
    },
  };
</script>

<style>
 
  #app {
    font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  }
  .child-view {
    position: absolute;
   
  }
  @-webkit-keyframes mask-play {
  from {
    -webkit-mask-position: 0% 0;
            mask-position: 0% 0;
  }
  to {
    -webkit-mask-position: 100% 0;
            mask-position: 100% 0;
  }
}

@keyframes mask-play {
  from {
    -webkit-mask-position: 0% 0;
            mask-position: 0% 0;
  }
  to {
    -webkit-mask-position: 100% 0;
            mask-position: 100% 0;
  }
}

.mask-nature1-enter{
  z-index: 20;
}

.mask-nature1-enter-to{
  /* current page */
  z-index: 30;
}

.mask-nature1-leave{
  -webkit-mask: url('../images/mask/nature-sprite.png');
          mask: url('../images/mask/nature-sprite.png');
  -webkit-mask-size: 2300% 100%;
          mask-size: 2300% 100%;
  -webkit-animation: mask-play 5.4s steps(22) forwards;
          animation: mask-play 5.4s steps(22) forwards;
}
.mask-nature1-enter-active{
  z-index: 20;
}



</style>
```

With that being an attempt to apply this effect for router-view.  I have created this Vue page where the css effect works during page load where I simply put two div on top of one another and apply the css to the top one.

(Below code works as CSS transition for two div on top of each other)

```html
<template>
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="css-mask" style='postion:absolute; background-image: url(./static/images/background1.jpg); z-index: 30'></div>
    <div class="top-left" style='postion:absolute; background-image: url(./static/images/background2.jpg);  z-index: 20'></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    components: {
    },
    mounted() {
    },
    beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
    },
    data() {
    },
  };

</script>

<style lang="css" rel="stylesheet/css" scoped>
  /*@import "./resources/assets/sass/variables";*/

  .css-mask{
    -webkit-mask: url('../../static/images/mask/nature-sprite.png');
            mask: url('../../static/images/mask/nature-sprite.png');
    -webkit-mask-size: 2300% 100%;
            mask-size: 2300% 100%;
    -webkit-animation: mask-play 5.4s steps(22) forwards;
            animation: mask-play 5.4s steps(22) forwards;
    /*-webkit-animation: mask-play 1.4s steps(22) forwards;*/
    /*animation: mask-play 1.4s steps(22) forwards;*/
  }

  @-webkit-keyframes mask-play {
    from {
      -webkit-mask-position: 0% 0;
      mask-position: 0% 0;
    }
    to {
      -webkit-mask-position: 100% 0;
      mask-position: 100% 0;
    }
  }

  @keyframes mask-play {
    from {
      -webkit-mask-position: 0% 0;
      mask-position: 0% 0;
    }
    to {
      -webkit-mask-position: 100% 0;
      mask-position: 100% 0;
    }
  }

</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to link `mask-nature1` to the keyframes,

```
.mask-nature1-enter-active {
  animation: mask-play 500ms ease-out forwards;
}
.mask-nature1-leave-active {
  animation: mask-play 500ms ease-out forwards;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I got it to work by having defined .mask-nature1-leave-active only.  Thanks.